# Azure Data Factory Stored Procedures

Tags: azure

I am putting together a brief comparison for a client (who is pro cloud) to show SSIS v Data Factory.  As I am new to the latter, I am trying to understand its workings and limitations.

In a nutshell:

Call a Stored procedure

Then in a loop:

dynamically call 2 stored procedures sequentially using values from the first procedure called

The thing is, there doesn't appear to be a way of calling a stored procedure, Just Azure Table, Azure SQL etc.  I'm assuming I will need to adjust the JSON myself?  If so, does anyone have any examples or URLs that explain this.  There seems to be little documentation on www for data factory in areas like this

Thanks

Comment: how can we use output parameter in pipeline (v2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a [stored procedure from Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-stored-proc-activity). You will require a SQL Server linked service, which is where the stored procedure will run.

You cannot dynamically call stored procedures in a loop, if you want to do this, i would recommend you just do it in the initial stored procedure, as this will be more efficient anyway.

At the moment you cannot pass parameters into a stored procedure from another, but you can [pass parameters relative to the slice that is running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-functions-variables) (slice time, etc.)

The JSON code for a single stored procedure looks like this:

```
{
     "name": "SprocActivitySamplePipeline",
     "properties": {
         "activities": [
             {
                 "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
                 "typeProperties": {
                     "storedProcedureName": "sp_sample",
                     "storedProcedureParameters": {
                         "DateTime": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}', SliceStart)"
                     }
                 },
                 "outputs": [
                     {
                         "name": "sprocsampleout"
                     }
                 ],
                 "scheduler": {
                     "frequency": "Hour",
                     "interval": 1
                 },
                 "name": "SprocActivitySample"
             }
         ],
          "start": "2016-08-02T00:00:00Z",
          "end": "2016-08-02T05:00:00Z",
         "isPaused": false
     }
 }
```

Comment: do you know if it possible to execute a SQL statement only? Instead of a whole stored procedure. I'd like to truncate a table before I run the other activities of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can set parameters of a stored procedure in your activity like this:

```
"storedProcedureParameters": {
                    "ProjectID": "0",
                    "StartDate": "2000/01/01",
                    "EndDate": "2100/01/01"
                }
```

You don't have the ability to run SQL statement in an ADF activity. Look at [custom activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities) in ADF pipelines. You have stored procedures, spark, hive, pig, etc. You can run a truncate statement in a simple stored procedure and this fixes your problem.